# Can't get 144Hz Refresh rate with display port to type-c adapter

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, usb-c

I have 2 questions actually.

Let me explain the situation first.

I have a monitor **(Dell S2716DG)** (2K-144Hz) with 2 ports.

1. Display Port 1.2 (capable of running 144Hz)
2. HDMI 1.4 (**NOT** capable of running 144Hz)

I have a laptop **(Dell G3-3590)** with 2 ports. (capable of giving 2K-144Hz)

1. USB Type-C (i don't know if it's capable of running 144Hz)
2. HDMI 2.0 (capable of running 144Hz)

After searching some shops, I found a Display port to Type-c converter that has a dp IN and Type-c OUT.

It detects display just fine. But when i change to 144Hz, it either reverts back to 60Hz or it disconnects the display. Also, it runs on 90Hz just fine (idk why)

Now i went to buy Dp to Hdmi converter, i found one but that also didn't work.

They showed me Hdmi to Dp converter but that was way too expensive.

Now my questions are:

1. **What will be the best possible solution so that i can connect DP to monitor and either type-c or HDMI to Laptop and get 144Hz ?**
2. **Is 144Hz not being displayed because of the DP to Type-c adapter? is it not capable of running on 144Hz or what's the reason for that ?**

Help will be highly appreciated.
Thankyou.

Comment: Please add to your post the exact models of your computer, display adapter and monitor.

Comment: The best method will be a monitor that supports HDMI 2.0 or an DisplayPort to HDMI 2.0 adapter. Without specifics of the Type-C adapter you tried this question is difficult to answer

Comment: Done, i don't know the model of display adapter. I can attach a picture if it helps?

Comment: @Ramhound so you are saying i should change my monitor for this?

because display port to HDMI adapter is very expensive here and I want another alternate if there is any

Comment: The adapter is expensive since they are active adapters one of the negatives of HDMI over DisplayPort

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the specs of the G3 3590, its USB-C port is noted as supporting DisplayPort Alt Mode (video output) when equipped with the
GeForce GTX 1650 or better.

If yours is such a model, you may be able to get by with a cheaper
adapter for USB-C to DisplayPort, since it is not an active adapter.
You should verify that the adapter supports 144Hz.

Whatever you buy, ensure that the vendor has a good return policy.

Comment: Okay i will find another adapter and check if it works.

Also, how is DP to Type-c direct Wire? how does it work? will it work in this case here?

Comment: I never met one - usually it's the other direction.

Comment: That's okay. Thankyou for your time

Answer (score 0):

HDMI output from laptop to DP input in monitor just won't work. That is a technological limitation. (An adapter might make it work but it will limit the specs, either resolution or refresh rate)

The best bet is USB C to DP here. Try searching for some adapters which might make it work. Even a normal good quality wire should make it work.

Comment: Did this come from chatgpt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @RohitGupta I am facing a similar issue. That's what I have been able to learn after reading many articles / verified answers. Check out my profile to see my question.

Answer (score 0):

If your display truly is limited to DisplayPort 1.2 (haven’t verified this), it requires a full 4 lanes to support 1440p at 144 Hz. Most USB-C to DisplayPort adapters are configured to provide only 2 lanes, to allow for USB 3 in parallel.

90 Hz is actually at 99% of the available bandwidth with 2 lanes.

Very few adapters exist that allow for 4 lanes in combination with USB 2. I used to recommend one from StarTech, but I can no longer find it. Note that while this setting *could* be user-configurable, most adapters do not expose a switch/selector for that.

Without a 4 lane adapter, you cannot fully utilize this display’s capabilities with your laptop. There is no other solution.